# Prove that for any $x \in \mathbb N$ such that $x<n!$ is the sum of at most $n$ distinct divisors of $n!$

Tags: factorial

Prove that every positive integer $x$ with $x<n!$ is the sum of at most $n$ distinct divisors of $n!$.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Comment: If only Goldbach conjecture was true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $x = nq+r$, with $0 \leq r < n$. Note that $x < n!$ implies that $q < (n-1)!$. Now use induction on $q$.

Comment: Works for me. Note that, as the initial case is 2! rather than 1!, this proves that $(n-1)$ divisors suffice.

Comment: Great, may I ask if you had seen a similar problem before or how you figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Khromonkey, I haven't seen this before. Induction seems to be a natural idea though. I guess that Robert Israel's attempt helped inspire this solution too.

Comment: No, this doesn't work, either.  Let $n=5, x=119$, then $q=23$ and $115$ doesn't divide $120$

Comment: @Ross Millikan, $q = 23 < 4!$, and you want to cut 23 up into sum of divisors of 4! first. For example, 23 = 12 + 8 + 3, and 119 = 60 + 40 + 15 + 4.

Comment: I see.  Thanks..

Comment: @WillJagy Or rather: As $r<n$ the summands are divisors of $(n-1)!$, i.e. $1\le x<(n+1)!$ implies that $x$ is the sum of at most $n$ distinct divisors of $n!$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, what you say may be true, but it doesn't follow from my proof, since for $1 \leq x < (n+1)!$ I need to multiply $n+1$ to the summands of $q$, making it possible that it doesn't divide $n!$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I posted my argument as a separate, and CW answer, just now.

Answer (score 3):

People do not seem to be going along with my comment. So this is CW, and directly from the answer by Sanchez.

For $n=2,$ we need only 1 divisor of $2!,$ as $1=1.$

For $n=3,$ we need only 2 divisors of $3!=6,$ as $1=1, 2=2,3=3,4=3+1,5=3+2.$

Induction hypothesis: for some $n \geq 2,$ we need at most $(n-1)$ distinct divisors of $n!$ to write any $1 \leq x < n!$ as a sum.

Induction step (Sanchez, above). Let $N = n+1.$ Let $1 \leq x < N! = (n+1)!$ Write
$$  x = N q + r, \; \; \mbox{with} \; \; 0 \leq r < N.   $$
Because $q < (N-1)! = n!,$ we need at most $(n-1) = (N-2)$ divisors of $n!$ to write $q$ as a sum. So
$$ q = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} d_i,   $$
where each $d_i | n!$ Therefore each $Nd_i | N!$

At this stage, we have at most $N-2$ divisors of $N!$ What about $r?$ Well, $r < N,$ so it is automatically a factor of $N!$ So we have finished the decomposition as a sum with at most $(N-1)$ divisors of $N!,$ where $N=n+1.$

CONCLUSION: For all $N \geq 2,$ every integer $1 \leq x < N!$ can be written as the sum of (at most) $N-1$ distinct divisors of $N!$

SUGGESTION: try it for $N=4, \; \; N! = 24.$

NEVER MIND, do it myself. Aliquot divisors 1,2,3,4,6,8,12. 
$$1=1,2=2,3=3,4=4,5=4+1,6=4+2,7=4+3, 8=8,9=8+1,10=8+2,  $$
$$11=8+3, 12= 12, 13 = 12+1, 14 = 12+2, 15 = 12+3, 16 = 12+4,$$
$$17=12+4+1,   18=12+6,19=12+4+3,20=12+8,$$
$$21=12+8+1,22=12+8+2,23 = 12+8+3.   $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note that $x = m (n-1)! + r$ where $0 \le m < n$ and $0 \le r < (n-1)!$.  Use induction.

EDIT: Oops, this is wrong: as Steven Stadnicki noted, $m (n-1)!$ doesn't necessarily divide $n!$.

Comment: $m(n-1)!$ isn't necessarily a divisor of $n!$, is it?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Then what is the correct answer?

Comment: I don't know.  I believe it is true, and probably not too hard to prove, that for any $x \in \{1,\ldots,n!\}$ there is always a divisor $y$ of $n!$ with $x/2 \le y \le x$.  Then we can take a 
greedy approach: let $y_1$ be the greatest divisor of $n!$ less than $x$, and replace $x$ by $x - y_1$.  This will result in writing $x$ as a sum of distinct divisors of $n!$, but it's not clear to me that there will be at most $n$ of them: the easy bound would be about $\log_2(n!) \approx n \log_2(n)$.

Comment: Can you edit or delete your answer please?? If it is wrong why is it here??

Comment: @Khromonkey, it is probably here because it is a reasonable direction to take, yet involves an error that has been identified. As such, it is educational for others. Meanwhile, noting that you say you are a high-school student, I cannot see how this is an ordinary homework problem, so I am asking why you think your assertion is true and where you got the problem.

Comment: I got it as homework on a math competition training camp

Answer (score 1):

Not quite there, but a start:  As suggested in [Wikipedia on practical numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number) we will use the greedy algorithm.  First pull out $n!/2$ if that is possible, then $n!/3$, then $n!/4$ and so on, stopping when the remainder is less than or equal to $n$ and skipping denominators that don't divide $n!$.  If $n$ and $x$ are very large, the denominators we use will follow [Sylvester's sequence](http://oeis.org/A000058):  $2, 3, 7, 43, 1807, 3263443, 10650056950807,\ldots$ which is given by $a(0)=2, a(n+1)=a(n)^2-a(n)+1$.  To use induction, we need to find a sequence of $m$ denominators that reduce $n!-1$ to something less than $n$.  For $n$ in the range $5-6$ we can use $2,3,8,30$.  For $7$ we can use $2,3,7,45$, for $8-10$ we can use $2,3,7,45,640$.  Then $44$ becomes available at $11$.  It "obviously" works, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 0):

A natural number $m$ is called [practical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number) if all smaller natural numbers can be represented as sum of distinct divisors of $m$.

The problem asks to establish that [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) numbers are practical. The wikipedia article on practical numbers even gives an algorithm, implemented in *Mathematica*:

```
dec2[0, n_] := {};
dec2[1, n_] := {1};
dec2[x_, n_] := Module[{fcts, pa, q, r, quo},
  fcts = Last[FactorInteger[n]]; pa = Power @@ fcts;
  q = Min[Quotient[x, pa], DivisorSigma[1, quo = Quotient[n, pa]]];
  Join[dec2[x - q pa, Quotient[n, First[fcts]] ], dec2[q, quo] pa]
  ]

dec[x_, n_] := Block[{$RecursionLimit = Infinity}, dec2[x, n!]]
```

Example:

```
In[32]:= dec[17, 4]

Out[32]= {2, 3, 12}

In[33]:= dec[137, 6]

Out[33]= {2, 45, 90}
```

It remains to be proven that the decomposition length of $x < n!$ will be less of equal than $n$.

Comment: That is the question. Can you make this answer answer it?